# How can I solve this question on Application of Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am self-educating myself. I have no tutors. I have joined a test series. It is a question which came in the test. I could not solve it in the test and I cannot solve it now also. So I seek your help.

[image]

Comment: Happy solving in Fiitjee AITS!!

Comment: @Rohan can you solve?

Comment: Maybe the most suitable self-study source of calculus is Howard Anton's. You may get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the given curve be $y = f (x)$. Suppose $P(x, y)$ be a point on the curve.

Equation of the tangent to the curve at $P$ is: $$Y-y = \frac {dy}{dx}(X-x) $$, where $(X, Y)$ is arbitrary point on the tangent.

Putting $Y = 0$, we get the intercept cut off by the tangent on x-axis = $$x-y\frac {dx}{dy} $$ Now given that $$x-y\frac {dx}{dy}=y \Rightarrow \frac {dy}{dx} =\frac {y}{x-y} $$ The equation of the curve satisfying this DE is given by $$yc =e^{-\frac {x}{y}}$$ where $c $ is some constant.  Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: How did you know that it is from FIITJEE AITS?